# I'm trying to fix a reference error when using Gulp 4, It won't watch my sass nor show the changes in the browser

Tags: gulp

I can't seem to figure out what the error is talking about. I set up everything else correctly but none of it works because of the error. And I can't seem to find this exact problem anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

I keep getting this error.

```
ReferenceError: watchFiles is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (gulpfile.js:42:29)
```

The specific code that the error is pointing to.

```
const watch = gulp.parallel(watchFiles, initBrowsersync);
```

the code above the error for context

```
function initBrowsersync(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app',
            index: 'index.html'
        },
        startPath: '/html'
    });

    done();
}

gulp.task('watchFiles', () => {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('style'));
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/css/*.css').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/javascript/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

The code below the error for context

```
exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watchFiles;
exports.default = watch;
```

and just below that are the other tasks I set it to run like uglify and minify-css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`const watch = gulp.parallel(watchFiles, initBrowsersync);`

to

`const watch = gulp.parallel('watchFiles', initBrowsersync);`

When using the `gulp.task('watchFiles',...` way of defining tasks, then your other references to that task must be as a string.

When using the  `function initBrowsersync(done) {` define a function version than you can refer to those tasks as a simple non-string function reference.

So your other option is to define `watchFiles` like so:

```
//gulp.task('watchFiles', () => {

function watchFiles() {
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('style'));
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/javascript/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
//});
};
```

and then you could use:

`const watch = gulp.parallel(watchFiles, initBrowsersync);`

I suggest this second approach.

Comment: It didn't work it gave me another error. I'm just going to rebuild the whole file again rather fixing something broken.

Comment: I'll leave the answer since it does correct the code you presented.

Comment: I rebuilt my gulp.js file. now everything works perfectly. Browsersync isn't working right but I'm wondering whether or not I actually need it since visual studio code live server extension streams the changes just fine with Gulp.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I use browserSync but only because I started with it before the live server extension was published and popular.